# Unable to read a file

Tags: java, file-io, bufferedreader

I am using the below code to read a data from a file:

```
BufferedReader br=null; 
try { 
    String str; 
    //C:\Sterling1\Test\OrderStatus 
    File ff=new File("H:/infilename.txt"); 
    boolean b=ff.exists(); 
    System.out.println(b); 
    br =new BufferedReader(new FileReader (ff)); 
    str=br.readLine(); 
    System.out.println(str); 
    // etc.
```

I am getting `false` when I try to validate the existence of file.
I have double-checked that the file is present, though.

This is the output (and error) I get when I run my program:

```
false
java.io.FileNotFoundException: H:\infilename.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at yiut.impl.tgt.MyFileReader.main(MyFileReader.java:25)
```

Please help me on this.

Comment: I checked quite below but couldn't find your code ;-)

Comment: I don't don't see "below program" any where and the error seems pretty self explanatory...

Comment: Is file `infilename.txt` is exist in Drive `H` ? Update your question with codes in `MyFileReader.java` in your program.

Comment: The problem is that the system could not find your file, did you check that it is in fact there?

Comment: I am sorry. missed to paste the code. BufferedReader br=null;

try
{
 String str;
 //C:\Sterling1\Test\OrderStatus
 File ff=new File("H:/infilename.txt");
 boolean b=ff.exists();
 System.out.println(b);
 br =new BufferedReader(new FileReader (ff));
 str=br.readLine();
 System.out.println(str);

Comment: Please add that code to your question, prefaced with four spaces so that it's formatted readably as code. And what's up with that `//C:\Sterling1\Test\OrderStatus`?

Comment: File is present in that directory

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your output you will see the word `false`

This is produced by your code

```
boolean b=ff.exists(); 
System.out.println(b);
```

It ain't there.

Comment: yes. you are right. Issue is i am getting false even though the file exist in that directory

Comment: It may exist for you (as the mapped drive H may exist for you), but it does not exist for the Java application.  Is the java application running as you?

Comment: How can i map H drive with java. Yes i am running this application in my local system

Comment: see this link http://www.coderanch.com/t/328372/java/java/Map-drive-access-Java-Application